# Split Unicode entities by graphemes

Tags: ruby, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization, grapheme

```
"d̪".chars.to_a
```

gives me

```
["d"," ̪"]
```

How do I get Ruby to split it by graphemes?

```
["d̪"]
```

Comment: You want to split at graphemes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: As @michau's answer notes, Ruby 2.5 introduced the `grapheme_clusters` method, as well as `each_grapheme_cluster` if you just want to iterate/enumerate without necessarily creating an array.

---

In Ruby 2.0 or above you can use `str.scan /\X/`

```ruby
> "d̪".scan /\X/
=> ["d̪"]
> "d̪d̪d̪".scan /\X/
=> ["d̪", "d̪", "d̪"]

# Let's get crazy:


> str = 'Z͑ͫ̓ͪ̂ͫ̽͏̴̙̤̞͉͚̯̞̠͍A̴̵̜̰͔ͫ͗͢L̠ͨͧͩ͘G̴̻͈͍͔̹̑͗̎̅͛́Ǫ̵̹̻̝̳͂̌̌͘!͖̬̰̙̗̿̋ͥͥ̂ͣ̐́́͜͞'


> str.length
=> 75
> str.scan(/\X/).length
=> 6
```

If you want to match the grapheme boundaries for any reason, you can use `(?=\X)` in your regex, for instance:

```ruby
> "d̪".split /(?=\X)/
=> ["d̪"]
```

ActiveSupport (which is included in Rails) also has a way if you can't use `\X` for some reason:

```ruby
ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.unpack_graphemes("d̪").map { |codes| codes.pack("U*") }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work in Ruby 2.5:

```
"d̪".grapheme_clusters # => ["d̪"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Unicode::text_elements` from [unicode.gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode) which is documented at http://www.yoshidam.net/unicode.txt.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'unicode'
=> true
irb(main):006:0> s = "abčd̪é"
=> "abčd̪é"
irb(main):007:0> s.chars.to_a
=> ["a", "b", "č", "d", "̪", "é"]
irb(main):009:0> Unicode.nfc(s).chars.to_a
=> ["a", "b", "č", "d", "̪", "é"]
irb(main):010:0> Unicode.nfd(s).chars.to_a
=> ["a", "b", "c", "̌", "d", "̪", "e", "́"]
irb(main):017:0> Unicode.text_elements(s)
=> ["a", "b", "č", "d̪", "é"]
```

Comment: Not everything can be normalised, so it's safer to use `s.scan(/\X/)` or `s.grapheme_clusters` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby2.0

```
   str = "d̪"

   char = str[/\p{M}/]

   other = str[/\w/]
```